# Why does Skype consume 100% CPU?

Tags: skype

Skype (4.0.0.4) consumes on my Zenbook with 12.04 everytime I make a call 100% CPU. Does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
vi /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
```

high-priority = yes

nice-level = -11

realtime-scheduling = yes

realtime-priority = 5

resample-method = src-sinc-best-quality

**Or get rid of all that pulse crap and  install libflashsupport**

Comment: `libflashsupport` is very outdated, any other suggestions as of 2017?

Comment: Skype 8.60 2020 does the same, 6 years from the original post. Any new relevant suggestions?